# Trigonometry Envelope Effect

Tags: trigonometry

I have the function of $x(t) = cos(48 \pi t) sin(3 \pi t)$. When it is plotted, it has an envelope effect and its envelope is equal to $sin(3 \pi t)$. My question is why it is equal to $sin(3 \pi t)$, instead of $cos(48 \pi t)$?

Comment: Because it is the factor with the lowest frequency.

Comment: Just as a side comment, the above has a "nice" envelope which *happens* to be one of the functions because $48 \pi$ is an integer multiple of $3 \pi$. That doesn't hold in general, look for example at $cos(11 \pi t) \cdot sin(3 \pi t)$.

Comment: @dxiv you are perfectly right.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $48 \pi  = 16 \times 3 \pi $,
so the cosine part makes 16 complete oscillations while the sine part makes one.